# Unmarshall and grab the nth item from the json array

Tags: json, parsing, go

I wanted to unmarshall the JSON and grab the second name "Andrey Borisenko" from the array of people,

**JSON:**

```
text = `{"people": [{"craft": "ISS", "name": "Sergey Rizhikov"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Andrey Borisenko"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Shane Kimbrough"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Oleg Novitskiy"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Thomas Pesquet"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Peggy Whitson"}], "message": "success", "number": 6}`
```

**My code so far:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)


type people struct {
    NAME string `json:"craft"`
}

func main() {
    const text = `{"people": [{"craft": "ISS", "name": "Sergey Rizhikov"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Andrey Borisenko"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Shane Kimbrough"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Oleg Novitskiy"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Thomas Pesquet"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Peggy Whitson"}], "message": "success", "number": 6}`
        textBytes := []byte(text)

    people1 := people{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(textBytes, &people1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(people1.NAME.[1])
}
```

Comment: Capitalize the `name` in `people`. It is not exported now. Unmarshal cannot set fields that are not exported.

Comment: This is the data I am getting from my JSON, I am not sure how can I capitalize it without even parsing

Comment: Capitalize the `name` field, not the data, that is: `type people struct { Name string }`

Comment: I did but that doesn't help.

Comment: You need to first unmarshal into a slice of people the fields you care about, then you can loop over the slice and pick the instance you care about. Other than that you'll have to write your own parser or use a 3rd party package, `encoding/json` does not support that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assignation with `json.Unmarshal` and your struct is not good for what you want to do.

You struct should look like this :

```golang
type myStruct struct {
    Peoples []struct {
        Craft string `json:"craft"`
        Name string `json:"name"`
    } `json:"people"`
}
```

Which will give you an array of people (`Peoples`)

```golang
    for _, eachOne := range peopleStruct.Peoples {
       fmt.Println(eachOne.Name) //eachOne.Name == name of you guys
       fmt.Println(eachOne.Craft) //eachOne.Craft == craft of you guys
    }
```

For Andrey : `fmt.Println(peopleStruct.Peoples[1].Name)`

[For live playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3WqB5AFmhCD)